# Running multiple ICs with a single crystal

Tags: digital-logic, adc, oscillator, signal, clock

I need to run three [AD7779](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7779.pdf) ADCs using the same clock signal for synchronization. I don't have access to an oscillator which I can use as a master clock, so I was wondering how I could use a single passive crystal to run all three ICs.

Comment: I don't think you can. The ADCs can't all be trying to drive the same crystal simultaneously. You need to produce a clock signal somehow first and at a quick glance it does not look like these ADCs have a clock output. If they did it would mean that one ADC could drive the crystal and output the clock which could then be fed to other ADCs.

Comment: Tombeki, Isn't there a section in the datasheet about synchronization? What about that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Why not use Sync_IN and Sync_OUT provided mechanism ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ADC you describe supports the use of a CMOS clock signal, as well as the use of a passive crystal. While you state that your selection of available components is limited, basic logic gates may be easier to source.

If you use a crystal alongside two inverter logic gates (one unbuffered, one Schmitt-triggered in the example below), you can then drive multiple chips from the output of the second logic gate.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN815m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This diagram is based on TI Application Note SCEA099 (https://www.ti.com/lit/an/scea099/scea099.pdf)

Comment: There are two resistors in the schematic of the application note. They might be necessary.

Comment: @Uwe an accidental omission, now rectified, thanks.

Comment: The (SN)74LVC1GX04 combines these two inverters.

Comment: @CL. Strange that that's a 1G part and not a 2G one.

Comment: @Hearth Presumably because it doesn't allow you to use them independently: it only has one input pin.

Comment: @Hearth They already used up the "2" for the 74LVC2G74 …

Comment: Could you also, after verifying that XTAL2 is the input and XTAL1 is the output, connect a crystal to one of the ICs as normal, and then connect all the XTAL2 pins in parallel?

Comment: @user253751 It's not something I'd guarantee to work: having three ICs loading the crystal may affect its resonance. (Some resonator circuits can play up when the small capacitance of a scope probe is attached!) The benefit of the above circuit is that the load of all the ADCs is placed on the Schmitt gate, but there's no additional load on the crystal itself.

Answer (score 3):

> I don't have access to an oscillator which I can use as a master clock

I don't quite understand what that means: you have to put an external oscillator in there - how would you not have "access" to it? You'd also need a clock distribution chip. The two can be all on one chip, see eg. the multitude of chips from Skyworx Solutions with several clock outputs.

> how can I use a single passive crystal to run all three IC's.

By using a crystal with an oscillator/driver chip that has at least 3 clock outputs. Each output goes to one of the ADCs. Done.

There's a **ton** of those chips on DigiKey.

Comment: I dont have access to DigiKey due to several reasons. I am limited by the domestic suppliers who dont have oscillators. I can only acquire a passive crystal. I was planning on creating a clock signal with the crystal using extra circuitry, then buffering it using SN74HC125

Comment: That could work (a roll your own clock distribution scheme).  How well do the clocks into each ADC have to be matched?  Is there a phase matching requirement?

Comment: @Tombeki You can buy an AD7779 and everything else it'll need to be useful but can't buy an oscillator chip? How is that possible?

Comment: With a 8.192 MHz crystal oscillator you don't need at least 3 clock outputs. A single output will do, routed to the three AD7779 ADCs. The total length of the clock line should be less than 100 mm. Only to achieve a very small phase difference between the ADCs the three  clock outputs may be needed.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to tie the crystal output pin XTAL1 through a buffer chip to the MCLK/XTAL2 input on two of the ADCs but I think it might be iffy. There's no guarantee the voltage swing is adequate.

I'd just add the oscillator, personally. It's tiny, cheap (eg. one similar to the 8.192MHz  one used in the eval board) and will be more reliable than the crystal. Those are not cheap ADCs, it would be good to get the most out of them.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to have a basic crystal oscillator circuit similar to what is inside the chip.

Make a Pierce oscillator with simple unbuffered inverter like 74HCU04 or 4069UB. Then you have a square wave out and can run it to two chips.

It might also be possible to use one chip as the oscillator, and then use the oscillator output on one chip to drive the oscillator input on the other chip.

Another option, if you have a MCU in the circuit, is to use a crystal on the MCU and in some way make it output a clock. Some MCUs have specific clock output pins. Some MCUs don't, so you could use hardware PWM output.

Comment: I was just looking at these when your answer appeared. At 3.3V here speed capabilities drop. 8192kHz may be marginal. At lower frequencies or highevoltages they should be fine.